# Upgrading to Mac OS X Lion from Snow Leopard then recover Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

As we know we can upgrade to Mac OS X Lion from Snow leopard 10.6.8.

Once this has been done, can we recover Snow Leopard again, or do we have to reinstall Snow Leopard?

Additionally, can we install Xcode 4? My main concern is if we can continue development with a lower version of Xcode or if we can only use iOS 5.

If there is any link to compare both operating systems can you please share?

Answer (score 0):

You must re-install (or restore from a Time Machine backup - you do have a backup right?)

Also, Lion requires the use of Xcode 4.1, which is available with the iOS 4 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of your answers, but...

- If you do a full backup before installing (eg Time Machine or some other copy routine), you could revert to that - not aware of any other option
- Xcode can be installed via App Store - but that will be the "released" version, ie no iOS5.  You need to install the beta of that.  Not sure about using anything earlier than Xcode 4.